# Bigquery user is not able to query an authorized view

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-platform, access-control

I have followed [this tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/share-access-views) on how to create authorized views on Bigquery. When the user tries to query the view, however, Bigquery says the user doesn't have access to query the source table. From the tutorial, it appears that as long as the view is an authorized view in the source dataset, users should be able to query the view which queries the underlying table. Here's a schematic of what I'm talking about:

- **Source Dataset**: `private_company`
- **Source Table in above Dataset**: `private_company_data`
- **Users View Dataset**: `public_company`
- **Authorized View in above View Dataset**: `public_company_view`

Expected behavior: User should be able to query `public_company_view` since `public_company_view` is an authorized view in the `private_company` dataset. User also has Bigquery.User rights in IAM.

Actual behavior: User is unable to query `public_company_view` because user does not have permission to query `private_company_data` (this is the error message I receive in Bigquery).

Comment: Works fine for me. Are you 100% sure that you've: 1) added the user correctly to the IAM? 2) shared the view dataset with them? 3) shared the source dataset with the view? If yes, then please post the exact error.

Comment: @GrahamPolley yes for 1) I added a separate google account I own as a "BigQuery > BigQuery User" by e-mail, not by group name (as mentioned in the tutorial) 2) I indeed shared the view since I am able to view the schema for the shared view from my separate google account 3) I indeed shared the source dataset with the view as explained [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/share-access-views#authorize_the_view_to_access_the_source_dataset)

Comment: Error I receive upon running the query from my separate google account: `Access Denied: Table cp11-174515:reports.Agency_Aggregate_Stats: The user ***@gmail.com does not have permission to query table cp11-174515:reports.Agency_Aggregate_Stats. `

Comment: And the view is definitely pointing to the correct table? is the SQL referencing any other tables in other datasets?

Comment: @GrahamPolley Yes the view is pointing to the correct table, in this case the `Agency_Aggregate_Stats` table. The query I'm running is a `SELECT * FROM cp11-174515:reports.Agency_Aggregate_Stats WHERE ID=***`

Comment: Sorry, then I'm stumped. Should be working. Works for me. Maybe a Googler can chime in and help.